# GNU Prolog 'consult' directive not responding on Mac

Tags: macos, gnu-prolog

I'm trying to look back at a run of some code I wrote earlier in the semester in GNU prolog. I move to the directory that is located. The file name is Project3_Name.pl 
I first type:

```
gprolog
```

It compiles leaving this message

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
Compiled Sep 18 2017, 19:40:04 with clang
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
```

I then try this line of code

```
consult('Project3_Name.pl')
```

then it just moves down to an empty line and doesn't respond at all.
I haven't messed with the file at all since I originally ran it correctly and I'm not receiving an error message now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the very simple answer to my simple problem....I forgot the period that you need to use after the consult line so it should look like

```
consult('Project3_Name.pl').
```

Derp